# How can I change mouse pointer size in Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, mouse-cursor

On my 4k screens, I like to crank up the mouse pointer size in windows.
[image: Setting windows mouse pointer to 4]

This is great for 95% of usage, but sometimes I need a small mouse pointer again for finer-precision work.
Unhappy that I have to open settings each time, I want a keyboard shortcut that I can use to toggle between big mouse and small mouse.

So I composed the following in the hope it would do the trick:

1. Update the registry with the new mouse size setting
2. Call `SystemParametersInfo()` with parameter `SPI_SETCURSORS` to jog the system to re-read the mouse settings.

Alas, no joy.

Can anyone point out the folly of my ways?
Cheers,
Dave

Code below:

```
param([int]$MouseSize=0)

###########################################
#
# DISAPPOINTINGLY  THIS DOES NOT YET WORK
# Need to figure out why
#
###########################################
 
##################
# Constants
##################
 
[int]$small_mouse = 48
[int]$big_mouse   = 80
[int]$min_mouse   = 1
[int]$max_mouse   = 256
 
[string]$path = 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors'
[string]$name = 'CursorBaseSize'
 
##################
# API Import
##################
 
Try{
    [void][SysParams]
} Catch {
Add-Type @'
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    public class SysParams {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, uint pvParam, uint fWinIni);
 
        public static bool RefreshCursor()
        {
            return SystemParametersInfo(0x0057, 0, 0, 0); // SPI_SETCURSORS = 0x0057;
        }
    }
'@
}
 
##################
# Main
##################
 
# Is $MouseSize passed in valid?
if ($MouseSize -ge $min_mouse -and $MouseSize -le $max_mouse) {
    $new_size = $MouseSize
} else {
    # If invalid $MouseSize passed in, toggle current mouse setting
    # First determine if current setting closer to $small_mouse or $big_mouse
 
    $current_size = (Get-ItemProperty $path).$name
    $diff_small = [math]::Abs($current_size - $small_mouse)
    $diff_big = [math]::Abs($current_size - $big_mouse)
 
    if ($diff_small -lt $diff_big) {
        $new_size = $big_mouse # Mouse is small, so toggle big
    } else {
        $new_size = $small_mouse # Mouse is big, so toggle small
    }
}

Set-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name $name -Value $new_size
$resp = [SysParams]::RefreshCursor()
```

Comment: Script works for me except that I need to relog for the cursor size to take effect. So the real question is, why isn't `SystemParametersInfo` call not working?

Comment: What do you mean by 'relog'? Do you mean log out and back in? If do that defeats goal of a quick toggle.

Comment: Yes. So somehow the interop code for `SystemParametersInfo` is not doing what it is supposed to do. I've tried a few other signatures, but no luck so far. Also added `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE` and `SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE` flags, but still not working.

Comment: Can you try setting the third parameter (`pvParam`) to `null` instead of `0`? [from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa) _If not otherwise indicated, you must specify NULL for this parameter._

Comment: As a last resort you can try to use UI automation .NET API to programmatically open the settings app and change the cursor size by moving the slider.

Comment: @Theo: I tried that and no joy. (From C p.o.v. NULL is defined as 0 - so makes no difference if you use 0 or NULL, just that NULL is convention for pointer values). Also tried setting the 4th value to ```SPIF_SEND­CHANGE = 0x02```. Had no effect either.

Comment: @zett42: That would be pretty awful. Screen appearing & disappearing. We should be able to do better.

Comment: I have also captured and pored over a trace of API calls using SysInternals' procmon64 in the hope that I could see the magic. Unfortunately nothing obvious stood out to me. Seems to read and re-write the cursor image files though.

Comment: You could try to temporarily change the cursor image. Maybe this triggers a size change as well.

Comment: Have you ever resolved this issue? Would love to get this working for myself as well

Answer (score 0):

**Get the current system parameters**

```
$systemParameters = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::Mouse
```

**Set the mouse pointer size**

```
$systemParameters.MouseSize = 20
```

**Update the system parameters**

```
[System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::Mouse = $systemParameters
```